# Update React component by key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app that has a tabbed interface of open files. The open files array looks like this:

```
[
  { name: 'file1', path: '/path/to/file1', fileContents: '...' },
  { name: 'file2', path: '/path/to/file2', fileContents: '...' },
  { ... }
]
```

Which are rendered into `<div>`'s like so:

```
render() {
  return this.state.files.map((file, i) => {
    return <div key={`tab--${file.path}`}> ... </div>;
  });
}
```

When my app renames the file, it re-renders the entire tab (since the `key` prop is now different due to the path update, React thinks it's a different component altogether and disposes of the previous element).

When rename "file2" to "file3", I would like my app to update the `key` from `tab--/path/to/file2` to `tab--/path/to/file3` without re-rendering the component at all - so just updating the `key` prop on the component.
Is there any way to find components by their `key` and subsequently update that `key`?

Comment: what's your use case? why do you assign the key at all in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys shouldn't be used to access components. They're just used to let react keep track of the components within that scope. I'd just use a unique value on `file` (like an id) for your key (so that React doesn't lose track of the components) and use ref (`<div key={i} ref={(f) => this[file.name] = f} />`) to access the components themselves (via `this[file.name]`).

You'll probably need to do some cleanup with `this[file.name]` still pointing to objects when `file.name` has been changed to something else, but this will get you closer to what you need, I think.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using a hash for the key - which works a charm.